# Solve long equation involving several exponential functions

Tags: exponential-function, approximation, lambert-w

I am trying to solve the following long equation for $\mu$:

$$\left((s_1-n)\mu + s_2\right) e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)(s_3-2\mu s_2+(n-s_1)\mu^2)}\left(e^{-\frac{(b-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}-e^{-\frac{(a-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)^{-1}=\Omega $$

where we have $s_1\le n$, $\sigma > 0$ ,$(b-\mu)^2< (a-\mu)^2$, and $\Omega\neq 0$. All quantities are real numbers except $n$, which is a natural number, and all quantities except $\mu$ are given.

**My question:** Is it possible to solve/approximate this equation for $\mu$, and if yes, can you show me how this can be done?

For $\Omega=0$, the task is much easier, and I get $\mu=\frac{s_2}{n-s_1}$. For the harder case $\Omega\neq 0$, I wanted to transform the equation into the form $f(\mu,n,a,b,s_1,s_2,s_3)e^{f(\mu,n,a,b,s_1,s_2,s_3)}=\Omega$ for some "simple" function $f$ and then use the Lampert-$W$ function, but I failed.

Comment: Can you just show you got the case of $\Omega=0$?

Comment: @SwastikSaha If $\Omega=0$, then $e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)(s_3-2\mu s_2 + (n-s_1)\mu^2)}\neq 0$, and since $(b-\mu)^2 < (a-\mu)^2$, it must also hold that $e^{-\frac{(b-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}-e^{-\frac{(a-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\neq 0$. So it follows that $(s_1-n)\mu+s_2=0$, and if we solve that for $\mu$ we get $\mu=\frac{s_2}{n-s_1}$

Comment: For "converging approximation technique," I'm guessing you would not be satisfied with "use a numerical solver to find close initial guesses, then use Newton's method." If that's the case, what further practical utility or theoretical insight are you looking for in an approximation technique?

Comment: @BenjaminWright I would like an approximation technique that converges to the true value in reasonable time, i.e., the number of iterations required to get closer that some $\varepsilon$ should be finite and a slowly growing function as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$